# Dynamic SelectMultipleField Flask Forms

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a `SelectField` in my form which is dynamically populated from a file upload occurring within my route. A snippet of the route is below and my entire form is also below. So, the behavior is a user reads in a data file and information in that file is used to populate the `SelectField` choices. This works just fine.

The dynamic populating of the `SelectField` works perfectly within my app but I need to update this to allow for multiple selections instead of just one. So, I have added this `SelectMultipleField` to my form and trying to use the same concept to dynamically update as I use for the `SelectField`. I am *assuming* the behavior regarding the arguments and inputs between these two would be similar, but perhaps am wrong.

In this case, it does not work and I get an error of `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`. Below is the portion of code from within my route:

```
vars = list(tab3.TestName.unique())
form2.test2use.choices = vars # note, this works as expected
form2.testing.choices = vars # just a test
```

And below is the form

```
class config_reports(FlaskForm):
    test2use = SelectField('Choose a test',  [DataRequired()], coerce=str)   
    #testing = SelectMultipleField('Multiple Options Should Appear Here', [DataRequired()], choices=[('A1', 'A1'), ('B1', 'B1'), ('C1', 'C1')])
    testing = SelectMultipleField('Multiple Options Should Appear Here', [DataRequired()], coerce=str)    
    submit = SubmitField('Run Report')
```

If I uncomment the hardcoded `#testing` and fill it in with choices and then try and change them dynamically as the file is read in I get an error of `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Any recommendations on how I should be dynamically populating the `SelectMultipleField` differently than `SelectField`?

Comment: For the second error "too many value to unpack". You set the choices and you try to override them within your route, according to the WTForm documentation: Note that the choices keyword is only evaluated once, so if you want to make a dynamic drop-down list, you’ll want to assign the choices list to the field after instantiation. Any inputted choices which are not in the given choices list will cause validation on the field to fail.
But maybe your problem could come from "vars". It expects a list of (str, str) tuples, not a list of strings.

Comment: @Victor I solved this problem with your suggestion. I create a list of tuples from `vars` and that indeed works. But, I believe the documentation on WTF forms is incorrect. For `SelectField` it reads "Select fields take a choices parameter which is a list of (value, label) pairs. It can also be a list of only values, in which case the value is used as the label." Then, for `SelectMultipleField` it reads"No different from a normal select field, except this one can take (and validate) multiple choices." Documentation I'm reviewing is here: https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/

Comment: So I have looked at the [WTForms code](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/src/wtforms/fields/core.py). Check the implementation of the function iter_choices line 511 and 557. The SelectField has this line: choices = zip(self.choices, self.choices) that the SelectMultipleField overrides. So, the SelectMultipleField requires the correct format or won't create a list.